# Getting "SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: content:" when i try to search for a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was trying to implement a simple search function to show any matching posts but i get the error "SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: content: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE (content LIKE '%po%' OR name LIKE'%po%')  ORDER BY created_at DESC"

controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    if params[:search]
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
  else
    @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end
  end

  def edit
    @posts = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
  @posts = Post.find(params[:id])

  if @posts.update(posts_params)
    redirect_to @posts
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

  def new
    @posts = Post.new
  end

  def create
      @posts = Post.new(posts_params)
    if @posts.save
        redirect_to @posts
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @posts = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def posts_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description)
  end


end
```

index page where the search is:

```
<p class="btn-minimal"><%= link_to 'Meu Blog', controller: 'posts' %></p>
</br>
<p class ="btn-minimal"><%= link_to 'New post', new_post_path %></p>

</br></br>
<h1>Lista de posts</h1>

<%= form_tag(posts_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Posts" %>
<%= submit_tag "Search" %>

<% end %>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" align="center">
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>

  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= post.title %></td>
      <td><%= post.description %></td>
      <td class="btn-minimal"><%= link_to 'Show', post_path(post) %></td>
      <td class="btn-minimal"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
</body>
```

post.rb model file:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :title, 
            :presence => {:message => "Title can't be blank." },
            :uniqueness => {:message => "Title already exists."},
             length: { minimum: 5 }

    validates :description, 
    :presence =>{:message => "Description can't be blank." }

    def self.search(search)
  where("content LIKE ? OR name LIKE?" , "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
end
end
```

can someone tell me whats wrong ?

Comment: The error says you don't have a `content` column in your `Posts` table. Look at your `db/schema.rb` what columns your `Post` model actually has.

Comment: no column content means you don't have that column in your database table - i think you want description? i.e. `where("description LIKE ? OR title LIKE ?" , "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")` - maybe you copy pasted the search method from somewhere and did not replace the column names properly?

Comment: oh thanks, yes i'm fowllowing a tutorial to learn some stuffs and i forgot to change the names to the names i gave them, sorry for being a noob, and thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

You likely do not have the proper columns in your database.

Run the following in case you created a migration.

```
bin/rake db:migrate
```

If you want to recreate the database from the schema you can run:

```
bin/rake db:drop
bin/rake db:create
bin/rake db:schema:load
```

Then you should be good.